# R - fast interpolation between CDF quantiles

Tags: r, parallel-processing, interpolation

Say we have a `data.frame` where the columns represent the quantiles for a given set of probabilities. Each row represents a different subject and the quantiles vary by subject. The goal is to take `n_draws` for each subject.

```
n <- 1e5
alphas <- c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95)
n_draws <- 100
dt <- data.frame(quantile_05 = runif(n),
                 quantile_25 = runif(n, min = 10, max = 20),
                 quantile_5 = runif(n, min = 30, max = 40),
                 quantile_75 = runif(n, min = 50, max = 60),
                 quantile_95 = runif(n, min = 70, max = 80))
```

R has `stats::approx`. The issue is that it can only be applied to 1 row at once.

```
draws <- apply(X = dt, MARGIN = 1, function(q){
  stats::approx(x=alphas, y=q, yleft = 0, rule = 2,  method="linear", xout = seq(.0001, .99999, length.out = n_draws))$y
})
```

Naturally, one way to speed this up is parallelization:

```
library(parallel)
registerDoParallel(cores=8)
cl <- makeCluster(8)
clusterExport(cl, c('alphas', 'n_draws'))
draws <- parApply(cl=cl, X = dt, MARGIN = 1, function(q){
  stats::approx(x=alphas, y=q, yleft = 0, rule = 2,  method="linear", xout = seq(.0001, .99999, length.out = n_draws))$y
})
```

This parallel code is several times faster on my machine. I am curious if anyone has suggestions for further speed ups.

To be a little more clear, this is just a simplification of what I'm using in real life. I have more than 5 quantiles. I want to use this concept to estimate not only other quantiles, but also the mean. Further, I'd like to use the draws to model other quantities like max(y - 10, 0) (or y - any arbitrary value).

Comment: If that was a "goal" set in a homework problem that included the word "random", then I don't think the text matches the solution. Those piece-wise linear approximations are not really random "draws". If the goal was to create a piecewise linear ECDF then that would succeed. In that case constructing a linear function with 6 knots might be faster. with

Comment: @IRTFM, not homework. It's a simplification of a real life problem. Maybe a better way to phrase it would be, creating the PDF from ECDF that is created from those quantiles

Comment: You didn't answer the implicit question: what's the endpoint? Do you want "draws" from an ECDF? You asked for a way to speed "it" up, and my second suggestion would appear to be faster than creating 100 interpolated points if you will probably only need to use a few of them for some sort of simulation effort.

Comment: @IRTFM yes, draws are the goal, to get an accurate estimate of the pdf and for things like mean and quantiles that aren't included in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed method is rather inefficient for the desired goal. You end up storing 100 points for each desired ECDF and you will still need to write a function to extract a desired draw. Instead I suggest you consider using the `approxfun` functions. It will return a more compact set of values which will be individual functions with associated environments that contain the knots for later calculation. The calculation will be done with a C call that is accessed with the invisible helper function, `.approxfun`.

Demonstrating the internals (up to a point) that I'm suggesting:

```
out <- approxfun(y=dt[1,], x=alphas,yleft = 0, rule = 2,  method="linear")
# So out is now a single instance using the knots in the first row

out
#function (v) 
#.approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f, na.rm)
#<bytecode: 0x558366535968>
#<environment: 0x5583690a04f8>

ls(environment(out))
#[1] "f"      "method" "na.rm"  "x"      "y"      "yleft"  "yright"
environment(out)$x
#[1] 0.05 0.25 0.50 0.75 0.95
environment(out)$y
#[1]  0.4038727 17.7069735 33.4438595 57.2753257 77.2024894
```

If you wanted the estimated 55th percentile for the first case, you could get it with:

```
out(55/100)
#[1] 38.21015
```

And now that I've suggested a way to speed up you creation of this list of functions, I'm not even sure it's worth it. I think you could just leave that `dt` dataframe in place and  call `approxfun` when needed. But that's your call.

Note: This is essentially the method used by the `ecdf` function:

```
ecdf
function (x) 
{
    x <- sort(x)
    n <- length(x)
    if (n < 1) 
        stop("'x' must have 1 or more non-missing values")
    vals <- unique(x)
    rval <- approxfun(vals, cumsum(tabulate(match(x, vals)))/n, 
        method = "constant", yleft = 0, yright = 1, f = 0, ties = "ordered")
    class(rval) <- c("ecdf", "stepfun", class(rval))
    assign("nobs", n, envir = environment(rval))
    attr(rval, "call") <- sys.call()
    rval
}
<bytecode: 0x558364a0f360>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

And it's possible that you might want to use the `ecdf` function because it has some class-associated functions.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I'm not sure it solves anything. `approx` returns draws from the ECDF, not the ECDF itself like `approxfun`. `approx` just skips the step of having to call your function `out`. The issue is that the approx family functions cannot operate on each row of the dataframe. Further, I need enough quantiles to model the mean, and my data is heavily right skewed.

Comment: I will agree it "doesn't solve anything" under those conditions, but it also does not give different results than your proposal. If all you have are those 5 quantiles then you are fooling yourself if you think you can model a highly skewed distribution with the simplistic linear interpolations. In particular the `approx` method will be giving you zeros for quantiles below 0.05 and all 0.95 quantiles for higher quentiles. So highly unlikely to allow any valid answers for skewed data situations.

Comment: Added some more detail to the question to clear it up

Comment: I don't think it clears up my concerns. I think you have just hidden the problem in code that doesn't actually do what you expect of it.